# Why is a `catch` block called if there is no `throw`?

Tags: ruby

The following:

```
catch :something do
  print true
end
```

will print `true` to the console. I thought the point of `catch` was that it was only called by a corresponding `throw`.

Less importantly, is there a one liner syntax? I was surprised that `catch :something { print true }` raises a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: In Ruby `catch` block is for `throw` what in some other languages `try` block would be, what can be pretty consfusing.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions. Your second question is totally unrelated to the first question, plus, it has been asked and answered dozens of times already on StackOverflow. No need to repeat it the n+1'th time (and getting an incomplete answer which only treats the symptom but doesn't explain the root cause, I might add, no offense to @sawa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Why is a `catch` block called if there is no `throw`?

  Perhaps there was `throw` before, and the programmer forgot to delete `catch` together when `throw` was deleted, or doesn't know how to use `catch`.

  But more likely in this case is that you failed to ask "why is a catch block **executed** if there is no `throw`?" The answer to that question is that `catch` block is executed to the point a `throw` is raised. If `throw` is not raised, then the `catch` block will be fully executed.
- Is there a one liner syntax?

  Yes. Don't omit the parentheses.

  ```
  catch(:something){print true}
  ```